# git LFS Smudge Error downloading file. Server misbehaving

Tags: git, ubuntu, git-lfs

So we have a git repo inside that it contains a submodule that has a bunch of binary files that are all LFS filtered (library files).

On windows using git 2.14.1.windows.1 I can do:

```
git clone <url>
git submodule update --init
```

And this inits and downloads all the submodule content no problem.

Then on Ubuntu 18 using get version 2.17.0 I can do the same commands:

```
git clone <url>
git submodule update --init
```

Only I get this error:

> ```
> Error downloading object <filename>: smudge error: Error downloading
> <filename> (<HASH>): batch reponse: Post
> <url.git>/info/lfs/objects/batch: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup
> <PCName> on <IP Address>: server misbehaving
> ```

I don't really understand what this means. But all my LFS files seem to have this same issue from the Ubuntu box (actually its a VM on my windows box). It can see all the same ip addresses that my windows box can see.

Using smartgit on the same Ubuntu VM I can sometimes get it to update the git submodules, but also sometimes it fails.

So really don't know how to proceed either debugging the issue or resolving it. My gut feeling is that it might be some timeout issue, but that is really a wild guess...

Comment: It's a network issue. Your VM is probably misconfigured—typically you want to have Virtualbox NAT the internal VM addresses, in which case this would work.

Comment: @torek Thanks for that. I have my VM (VirtualBox) set to network settings `attached to: NAT`. But I am not sure what you mean regarding "NAT the internal VM addresses" is that something more that I need to do? thanks : )

Comment: That sounds like the right setting. I'm not sure what else is going wrong here, then—but it's definitely a networking thing.

Comment: @torek thanks for the pointers Torek ... just for my benefit, why do you think it is definitively a network thing? - is that what server misbehaving means?

Comment: Yes: your Git-LFS file-reader needs to reach out over the network to get the large files from some server, and it's failing to speak successfully with this server. The next step is to figure out why it fails, but I don't use Git-LFS and can't really help there.

Comment: @torek Indeed it was a network issue! - we had some strange proxy setting. I definatly would not have looked there without your help - so please feel free to add that as an answer and I will mark it up :)

Comment: At this point you might as well just answer your own question (it's allowed, even encouraged if no one else answered it!).

Answer (score 0):

As Torek pointed out, this turned out to be a network setting that was incorrect within my Ubuntu VM. I had some old proxy settings that where getting in the way - turned them off and everything started working again :)